# Tangoverflow - StackApps API using D with Tango

Tags: library

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

Not yet available.

### About

So far, in commit #2, can successfully parse the statistics API into an object.  I'll update more as I get more of the API done (but for now, I need to go take a bike ride and enjoy the outdoors a bit).

#### License

Available under the [MIT license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php).

#### Download

Development branches available on [Launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Emark.rushakoff/tangoverflow/dev).  I was going to put it on Github, since I know many more SO users use that -- but I was having some SSH issues that I didn't want to take the time to resolve.

#### Platform

It should run anywhere that D 1.0 with Tango can be compiled.

### Contact

Just me (Mark Rushakoff) (so far!).  Contact me through Launchpad if necessary, or post/comment here.

### Code

Written in D 1.0 with Tango, hoping to have no other dependencies.  Code available on [Launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Emark.rushakoff/tangoverflow/dev) as mentioned before.  Check out the first part of the API that's been finished yet ([Statistics.d](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Emark.rushakoff/tangoverflow/dev/revision/2)) for a look at how elegant D's mixins can be.

Contributions certainly welcome, submit through Launchpad.

Comment: The message I get is `"No command 'dmd' found."` What exactly is dmd?

Comment: @George: `dmd` is the Digital Mars D compiler.  GDC should be equivalent, but I think it installs something like `run-dmd.sh` as a wrapper to translate the `dmd` arguments to GDC syntax.  Even so, all that's going on in `build.sh` is compiling all `*.d` files with `-unittest` specified, then running the executable to verify the unit tests.  The other option in the latest build is to do `dmd -debug=statistics -run statistics.d` which will download, parse, and print out information from `/stats`.

Comment: @Mark: Ah, okay. That makes sense.