# OBSOLETE - SOREP: Trilogy Site Ranking - For those who need to know

Tags: app, website, obsolete

## Note, all of the app links, below, are dead. And the domain is parked.

---

---

---

**SOREP** is a service that does a nightly index of all users ordered by reputation and makes that information available via REST.

The primary use of this information is to add a `top xx%` to your [flair](https://stackapps.com/users/flair). See examples below. The `top xx%` has a mouseover that indicates your acutal ranking, e.g. `392 out of 148,200`.

This service has been running for some months using screen scraping but upon creation of SOAPI-CS I figured I would dogfood it on my own stuff.

I am pleased to say that not only is using the API (and SOAPI-CS) much faster, it also reduced the complexity of the code by orders of magnitude. I am pleased.

### Original announcement:

I see a few questions on meta.stackoverflow.com regarding user ranking. There are several existing lists but they are focused primarily on users with higher scores.

So, I wrote a small applet that, via a trickle pull, indexes all users for the trilogy and meta down to the 100 rep mark, in order of appearance.

The 100 rep cutoff seems reasonable. On StackOverflow, the vast majority of users are < 100 and pulling that data seems over the top frivolous.

You may access this data in several ways

**INTERACTIVE:**

http://skysanders.net/tools/sorep/default.aspx (detailed usage information here)

**AUTOGET:** (for you Benjol)

http://skysanders.net/tools/sorep/default.aspx?site=stackoverflow.com&userId=1

**JSON:**

http://skysanders.net/tools/sorep/SEStats.ashx?site=stackoverflow.com&userId=1

**JSONP:**

http://skysanders.net/tools/sorep/SEStats.ashx?site=stackoverflow.com&userId=1&callback=foo

**Flair**

An example of using ranking in Flair is available on the interactive page.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... Jeff's StackApps score is missing... see below!

Comment: @George - The page and this post's content are several months old. I just updated the indexing service to use the API. I will have to find myself with some elusive non-allocated time to bother with details like that.

Comment: It's just a joke :)

Comment: @code: The demo on your site has stopped working.

Comment: @geo - all systems are green and it is behaving as expected. what problem are you having?

Comment: @code: Oh, nvm. It's working now. Before, the site drop-down was empty.

Comment: @geo - skysanders.net is a hosted site and they cycle down idle appdomains. if it has been idle for a while, it has to come back up and jit some code. sometimes it takes a sec.

Comment: I was trying this, and the results seemed really old.

Answer (score 2):

I see that the only reason you didn't include Jeff's StackApps score is because **I** have the top spot!

http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/stackapps_me.png

Jokes aside, that is awesome and I can't wait to play with it further.

Comment: Actually I just copied the announcement from the meta.stackoverflow question. There was no api or stackapps then. I chose jeff because his userid was all 1s across the board (and homage to those with the kill button is never a bad idea).

Comment: Right... but you can only guess how I feel knowing that Jeff is in the top 1% for every site but this one - and I'm beating him.