# -430 rep - why?

Tags: support, meta

I just lost 430 rep. from 6777 earlier today to 6347.

This seems to be localized to my account only.

Why?

Comment: @codepoet Has some of your questions and/or answers been deleted in the past? Rep earned from deleted posts are not deducted until there is a rep recalc, to the best of my knowledge. It seems likely that a rep recalc occurred on your account recently.

Comment: @coo - the only deletions I have experience, to my knowledge, have been at my own hand. And sure, there was an upvote here and there but nothing that would account for this, even with a recalc.

Comment: @kia - maybe. but i suspect that the cause and effect are related to ongoing localized 'discussions' and as such would have no relevance on meta.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - I agree in principle, but reasoned just like @code poet for some topics as well more often than not as of today, see my similar exchange with George Edison in the comments to [Why could it possibly be considered ‘reputation farming’ asking for solutions to real world API use cases?](http://stackapps.com/questions/1427). It's unfortunate that we don't have a Stack Apps specific Meta site yet, as almost all other Stack Exchange sites do have by now, and this need becomes more obvious almost daily at the moment ...

Comment: Have you by chance some former reputation audits of yours persisted (e.g. I remotely recall you posting one occasionally while demonstrating some API stuff)? Diffing these against a current one might allow to encircle the responsible posts eventually.

Comment: @steffen - sorry, this got buried. nope. don't have anything like that. it is obvious the votebot ate a bunch of votes, i watched it do it, 16 of them, but that does not add up to -430. I was the only person that day to have lost rep that day (i do have everyones rep every (almost) day archived see http://stackapps.com/questions/543) so I suspect manual action against my account. but that is neither here nor there. I am dissatisfied with the handling of many things, this included, but it is clear that the wagons are circled and I am not on the inside. oh well. time to move on.

Answer (score 3):

`ScheduledController.InvalidateVotes()`

This means the vote anomaly detector saw a statistical anomaly in votes cast to your account (up or down) and invalidated them.

Comment: as I suspected. I provide volumnuous substantive documentation and a few of the users of the library are quite pleased with them and indicate so with upvotes. The votebot I understand, but it seems that the users are not regaining the ability to recast, i.e. vote count and points are revoked but their upvote flag remains set. From what I read this should not be the case once the votes are revoked.

Comment: also, this would mean that 43 votes were cast in one day and the votebot cancelled them. this is not the case - i watched 15 votes on newly posted documentation go poof at the same time -430 was logged. something else seems to be going on.

Comment: Ew... what is that funny line of code?

Answer (score 1):

This is weird indeed:

- You already stated that you are not aware of any deleted posts of yours, which is the primary reason for such reputation losses.
- We already covered the conversion of the [`dev-tip`](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/dev-tip) posts into Community Wiki posts in Matts answer:

  - *The original author keeps the reputation gained (or lost) before their post entered community mode* (see [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741), question *How do Community Wiki posts work?*).
- I just reassured that me working through your nice *QuickStart* [documentation series](https://stackapps.com/questions/1433/soapi-js2-a-fully-relational-javascript-client-library-for-the-stack-exchange-a#1441) of [Soapi.JS2](https://stackapps.com/questions/1433/soapi-js2-a-fully-relational-javascript-client-library-for-the-stack-exchange-a) and voting on each of the posts respectively for +8 there (plus maybe another vote on that day) has not been considered vote fraud, which is another major reason for such reputation losses (see [What are the mechanics of vote fraud handling?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/62066/what-are-the-mechanics-of-vote-fraud-handling-i-e-not-the-detection-heuristics)):

  - I can still see all my votes, hence they have not been considered fraudulent and removed.

I still wouldn't be too surprised to find some other earlier votes of mine reverted, as I've been tracking your activities pretty closely and, given your impressive pace, may have exhibited 'suspicious' voting patterns, for example by voting too fast on several posts (I regularly trigger the posting captcha and other UI throttles ;)

- However, according to [Diagos answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/62066/what-are-the-mechanics-of-vote-fraud-handling-i-e-not-the-detection-heuristics/62069#62069) this should have been detected within a 24 hour time frame back then already, hence would only be possible, if the scripts are run differently over here, which is doubtful.

So this might only be resolvable by moderator analysis, though [Diagos answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/62066/what-are-the-mechanics-of-vote-fraud-handling-i-e-not-the-detection-heuristics/62069#62069) again seems to indicate that this might not even be (easily) possible; at least I've seen such analysis before, maybe there are some inside paths available to someone in charge still.

Looks like one should regularly persist the [reputation audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation) at least to allow for diffing and eventually encircling such cases later on ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'll be willing to bet money that it was because of all those non cw dev-tip posts being converted to cw

Comment: -1 - you just lost your money ;) See [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741): In question *How do Community Wiki posts work?* it is stated that *The original author keeps the reputation gained (or lost) before their post entered community mode.*!

Comment: Oh darn it!!! I lost my moneys!

Comment: you might update your answer regarding my comment and get a refund accordingly, after all, this is not Las Vegas ;)