# SOREP V2: Ranked Flair Take 2

Tags: app, soapi.cs, flair

### [SOREP V2](http://stackusers.com/Users/Flair): Ranked and aggregated flair

### About

[SOREP V2](http://stackusers.com/Users/Flair) is a flair service that is built upon the [StackUser](https://stackapps.com/questions/1573) platform that provides ranked flair, both in standard layout and themes as well as custom aggregations.

- Site Ranking, both as an ordinal value and a mouseover percentile.
- Aggregated flair - all or specific number, sorted by reputation
- All standard themes supported - `default`, `clean`, `dark`, `hotdog`
- Custom display formats - `default`, `small`, `tiny`
- Easy selection using a variety of identifiers

  - user id and site

  [`/users/flair/{user_id}/{site_url}`](http://stackusers.com/Users/flair/1/stackoverflow.com)

  - email address

  [`/users/flair/{email address}`](http://stackusers.com/Users/flair/jatwood@codinghorror.com)

  - association id

  [`/users/flair/{association_id}`](http://stackusers.com/Users/flair/febfb878-3f6f-4215-9323-46d15d62ac7d)

**Default flair layout**

[image]

**Small flair layout**

[image]

**Tiny aggregated flair layout**

[image]

See http://stackusers.com/Users/Flair for more guidance.

### Contact

Sky Sanders - [support@stackusers.com](http://mailto:support@stackusers.com)

### History

Since early this year, before the advent of the API, [SOREP](https://stackapps.com/questions/543) has been providing ranked flair for the big 4 trilogy sites. With the advent of the API and improved access to data (so long screen scraping!) the groundwork for [SOREP V2](http://stackusers.com/Users/Flair) with an improved api and layout was put into motion with the [Soapi.CS](https://stackapps.com/questions/386) client library upon which the [StackUser](https://stackapps.com/questions/1573) data platform is built.

Comment: To say nothing of the upcoming StackImage2... :)

Comment: Excellent - I thought about an Area 51 alike aggregate based upon Soapi.JS for a second, but expected you to update SOREP anytime soon anyway, so thanks much for providing an even better server based approach via Soapi.CS/StackUser now :)

Comment: @steffen - if we take ranking out of the picture, a client script flair is a perfect use case for soapi.js2. That should be doable in just a few hours. I will knock out a simple implementation today unless you would like to take it. I will make the latest soapi.js2 available to you.

Comment: @Sky: What's left to be done before Soapi2.JS final is released?

Comment: @geo - I am working on the soapi.cs<->soapi.js story while dog-fooding. progress is spotty as the main focus is getting stackusers platform finished. there is no rushing it but I will try to publish a current version of js2 tonight so you don't get hammered by breaking changes later.

Comment: @geo - check it out, i added the special 100th percentile title just for you. ;-) http://stackusers.com/Users/flair/18/stackapps.com?mode=tiny&count=0

Comment: @Sky: Awesome! The whole thing looks great!