# Dev-Tip: How to call the API in C# and Silverlight

Tags: discussion, c#, silverlight, dev-tip

This tip shows a simple and reliable way to create `HttpWebRequest` that are configured to properly query the api.

With the exception of the `AutomaticDecompression` assignment, this code can be used in Silverlight.

#### Example as Test

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace StackApps.Tips
{
    public class SimpleRequestFactoryFixture
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            string yourApiKey = "";

            Uri methodUri = new Uri("http://api.stackapps.com/0.9/questions/unanswered");

            var parameters = new NameValueCollection
                                 {
                                     {"sort", "votes"},
                                     {"min", "5"},
                                     {"order", "asc"}
                                 };


            HttpWebRequest request =
                SimpleRequestFactory.Create(methodUri, parameters, yourApiKey);

            Console.WriteLine(request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri);

            string json;

            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(json);
        }
    }
}
```

#### The Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

namespace StackApps.Tips
{

    public class SimpleRequestFactory
    {
        // this value is a guess, have not tested yet
        public const int MaxQueryStringLength = 1000;
        // this value is verified
        public const int MaxPathLength = 240;

        private const string MaxPathErrorMessage
            = "Path length exceeds maximum recommended value of {0}";
        private const string MaxQueryStringErrorMessage 
            = "Query string length exceeds maximum recommended value of {0}";


        public static HttpWebRequest Create(Uri url, NameValueCollection parameters, string apiKey)
        {
            string queryString = String.Join("&", parameters.AllKeys
                .Select(
                    name =>
                        String.Concat(name, "=",
                        HttpUtility.UrlEncode(parameters[name])))
                        .ToArray());

            var fullUrl = new Uri(String.Format("{0}?{1}{2}", url.AbsoluteUri,
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiKey) ? "" : String.Format("key={0}&", apiKey)
                , queryString));


            if (fullUrl.AbsolutePath.Length > MaxPathLength)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(String.Format(MaxPathErrorMessage, MaxPathLength), "url");
            }


            if (fullUrl.Query.Length > MaxQueryStringLength)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(String.Format(MaxQueryStringErrorMessage, MaxQueryStringLength), "url");
            }

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fullUrl);
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

            return request;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I spent the whole afternoon trying to figure out what I was doing wrong. The GZIP compression line fixed everything!

Comment: @diago - my pleasure. If you would like a full featured .net client library - check out http://stackapps.com/questions/386/

Comment: Thanks. It looks good. I want to wrap my head around how the API works first before moving to using a library.