# geek score calculator - SO + Github on Rail

Tags: app, website, ruby

I am learning Rails and this is my first application built on Rails 2.3.8.

http://g33k.heroku.com

[image]

License: Free to use

Code: http://github.com/utkarsh2012/g33k-score-calculator

Platform: Hosted on Heroku

Ruby on Rails

Comment: I am 62.5% geek! Yay! :) Nice idea.

Comment: Is this using the API, or does it just scrape the user page?

Comment: I'm 100% geek? No surprise here :)

Comment: I don't know I think the numbers need a little more adjusting... Seems a little too easy if you ask me.

Comment: @jjnguy I am requesting JSON data and parsing out data from that.
@thyrgle Yup, its very simple. I have just started learning Ruby and Rails, was built over a weekend.

Comment: @zengr Ok.  Why are you requesting that people enter their entire URL, instead of just their ID?

Comment: Please follow the rule given here: http://stackapps.com/q/7/2951

Comment: @jjnguy Yes, actually, I did not find a way to look up a user's data using their username, but I needed their unique ID (eg: 231917 and not zengr). Is there a workaround?

Comment: @chanchal1987 Updated.

Comment: usernames (`display_name`) is not unique thus not a valid target for a programmatic lookup. You will need to provide a search-and-select workflow for this. Something similar to http://stackapps.com/questions/1344/

Comment: Yup, I prefer one step rather than two.

Comment: Could also use: number of commits, number of people who forked one of my repos.