# Posting questions and answers via API

Tags: discussion, getting-started

I am new to StackApps. I have created an account and I have got an API key.

Now my question is, how can I access user accounts? I'm interested in posted questions and 
answers. Is there a way to post a question or answer programmatically?

A C# .net example would be preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not post data to the api but retrieving data in c# is quite simple.

- Create a project and [get an api key](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register). To get started, just make use your project's name, whatever it is and your profile url as the app's website. This information can be modified at any time in the future.
- Download the source code for [Soapi.CS](https://stackapps.com/questions/386)
- Either build or add a project reference to Soapi.net35 or Soapi.net40 to your project

and from there, it is quite simple

```
var context = new ApiContext(apiKey).Initialize(false);

var site = context.find("http://stackapps.com");

var skysQuestions = site.Users.ById(14).Questions.ToList();

foreach (Question in skysQuestions)
{
  Console.WriteLine(Question.Title);
}
```

Comment: So how would one of my users actually submit a question?

Comment: @user: They would have to do it through the site itself.

Comment: i added soad.dll as reference but i cant get Question as the Key word .. where did i go wrong

Answer (score 5):

The current version of the API is read only, meaning you can not have users login and post answers/comments/questions. Theres documentation on the API, which you can get by click on the API documentation and help just here on the right column >>>>